# Terraform clone git repo at plan or init stage

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, openapi, terraform-provider-aws

**Context:**

I am building API Gateway with OpenAPI Specifications 3.0 using terraform. I have got the `api-spec.yaml` file in a different repo from the terraform code. So, here's what I have done so far.

1. Using null_resource to clone the repo at the desired location

```
resource "null_resource" "clone-spec-file" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "git clone https://gitlab.com/dShringi/openapi-spec.git"
  }
}
```

2. Using the cloned api-spec file while creating the api gateway resource

```
data "template_file" swagger {
  template = file("./openapi-spec/api-spec.yaml")
  depends_on = ["null_resource.clone-spec-file"]
}
```

**Problem:**
The script fails at terraform plan because although I have used `depends_on` with `template_file`, it doesn't actually clones the repo at plan stage but it checks if the file is present and hence it fails with file not found at `template = file("./openapi-spec/api-spec.yaml")`.

Will appreciate any thoughts regarding how it can be best handled, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a git submodule to load the `openapi-spec` repo inside the repo with the terraform code?

Comment: I wasn't aware of git submodules and it looks promising, I will give it a go, thanks!

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this yet?